# Let $f$ be a function such that $f(x) = f(1-x)$ for all real numbers $x$. If $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then $f'(0)$

Tags: derivatives, gre-exam

I do not know how to solve this question:

> [image]

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: hint : let $g(x)=1-x$ and use chain rule

Comment: Intuitively, we can note that $g(x) = f(x + \frac 12)$ is an even function.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   I do not understand what do u mean.

Comment: The function $g(x) = f(x + \frac 12)$ satisfies $g(x) = g(-x)$.  In other words, it's an "even function". It is well known (and arguably intuitive) that the derivative of an even function is an odd function.

Comment: First find $f'(x),$ then plug in $0$ in place of $x,$ then see where it goes from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Differentiating both sides of $f(x)=f(1-x)$ leads to
$$ f^{\prime}(x)=-f^{\prime}(1-x)$$
by the chain rule. Now plug in $x=0$.